Which English Bibles stylistically present quotations in a different font? What's the origin of this practice?
It's common to see Jesus's words in red in a lot of bibles.  However, I have been appreciating the Christian Standard Bible team judiciously bold-ing OT references that are clear enough when the authors intended the phrase as an OT quotation, such as in 1 Cor 15:42-46:

42 So it is with the resurrection of the dead: Sown in corruption, raised in incorruption; 43 sown in dishonor, raised in glory; sown in weakness, raised in power; 44  sown a natural body, raised a spiritual body. If there is a natural body, there is also a spiritual body. 45 So it is written, The first man Adam became a living being;[a] the last Adam became a life-giving spirit. 46 However, the spiritual is not first, but the natural, then the spiritual.
a. 15:45 Gn 2:7

making it easier for us to recognize how 1 Cor 5:45 refers to Gen 2:7, even though other translations have the footnote as well.
See more examples from the entire chapter 15.  Especially interesting is Acts 2:17-21 where there is a mixture of bolded words and regular words.  Is it possible this is to show how Luke added words to the OT verses, which is helpful to get more insights in how NT authors used OT?  Example (v. 17, line breaks ignored):

And it will be in the last days, says God, that I will pour out my Spirit on all people; then your sons and your daughters will prophesy, your young men will see visions, and your old men will dream dreams.

My question: Which English Bibles have this "feature"?  What's the origin of this practice, which maybe in a non-English Bible translation?

Manipulating the text in any way whatsoever is forcing an interpretation upon the text.

@NigelJ So you frown on red lettering Jesus words too, that many KJV editions have?  How about adding footnotes for alternate English rendering and cross references?  On the same principle how about removing pericope headings, chapter numbers and verse numbers too?  When the text itself is unchanged, only the typography, people can see clearly which are the editorial additions, so I don't see how it can be a negative.

@NigelJ wouldn't that include translating and even adding punctuation, distinguishing capital/lower case letters, verse and chapter numbers?

NET has that feature. and NASB has it in capital

@Michael16 Interested to write an answer for it?  BTW looking at chapter 15 NASB they italicized words too; I wonder what's the meaning and principle behind it

@DarkMalthorp Yes, it would. Great care has to be taken not to intrude upon the text and not to interpret. There is no harm in cataloguing the text into sections so that one may retrieve content from it. But that should never be taken to have a meaning.

@DarkMalthorp says "wouldn't that include …" — and deciding whether to include "the" in the translation (e.g. "shall your heavenly Father give the Holy Spirit to them" versus "shall your heavenly Father give holy spirit to them") is very much a doctrinal decision.

@NigelJ it does have the potentially harmful effect of implying that a chapter is an intentional pericope and things of that nature. But I think what GratefulDisciple is asking about would fall under the category of punctuation.

@NigelJ Here are 2 scanned pages from KJV 1611 around 1 Cor 15.  There are margin notes and pericope headings not inline but at the beginning of each chapter.  So the tradition of including pericope headings is quite old; there is even topic printed prominently on the top of each page, such as "The resurrection is prooued.", "Our victory.", "Stand in faith."

@NigelJ What surprised me the most, though, is that there are words in a smaller font such as 1 Cor 15:14 "Then commeth the end, when he shall have delivered up the kingdome to God, even the Father; when he shall have put downe all rule and all authority and power."  The word "commeth" is in a different font but the distinction is missing in a modern KVJ.  What do you think of this typographical enhancement and what the smaller font words signify?  Should I ask another question for this?

@RayButterworth You raise a very important point there, that a Bible printer needs to make a decision one way or the other.  Something needs to be printed, and there is no gray area (other than including footnotes).  Otherwise we go the route of printing the original Hebrew/Greek text, the Hebrew without vowels and the Greek without any punctuation (or even spaces between words?), which then compromises the infallible doctrine (how can God's Word produce an effect in one's heart if it is not properly understood)?

@DarkMalthorp In addition to sentence breaks, punctuations, and capitalizations, articles (like "the"), we can already see paragraph marks in the KJV 1611 too, which can also influence meaning.  KJV 1611 even has the running topic on each page; don't tell me that that doesn't influence the reader!

@DarkMalthorp So I think bolding quotation, even though it IS interpretation, is arguably LESS INTRUSIVE than running topic, paragraph marks, articles, chapter & verse numbers, punctuations, pericope headings, and footnotes.  It's definitely ON PAR with red lettering, calligraphy of the first letter of a chapter, and the little font in KJV 1611 (probably to indicate words added by the translator to make the translation a little more dynamic, since KJV is quite literal), typographical features that the reader can easily distinguish and ignore.  Ease to ignore should be the measure.

Of course, the more hugely important issue is that of the Greek text, the introduction of the Critical Text (Westcott & Hort/Nestle Aland) beginning in 1881, the placing of far too much empahsis on Sinaiticus and Vaticanus, part of a Coptic recension in the 4th century which is to be avoided not followed. (See Hermon Hoskier Codex B and its Allies and John Burgon Revision Revised). But yes, the KJV (and Young's Literal) are noteworthy and exemplary in showing italics where wording is added, for the sake of English idiom, that is not there in the original.

@NigelJ Yes, I actually wish that later KJV editions preserve the italic.  But original language text edition is a completely different issue.  For this question it's about typography.  I just don't see the negative when it's so easy for the reader to ignore, more easy than the much more covert capitalization, articles, punctuations, and sentence & paragraph breaks that CAN influence meaning.  Don't you think so?  What do you think of line breaks for OT poetry (such as Psalms) according to Hebrew poetry metrical system?  I argue that it DOES influence interpretation, though in a good way.

@NigelJ Here's 1 Cor 15 in Young's Literal Translation, 1898.  Yes, there is no "cometh" in v. 24.  but there are plenty of dashes (same category of punctuation) that to me are helpful to parse Paul's extra long sentences (sentence breakdown that WE ADD, inferring from Paul's grammar, so that's an interpretation).  Are you okay with those dashes?  Anyway, seems that the translation improves the literal-ness and faithfulness to the TR compared to KJV, is that the big plus of YLT?

Good question...can of worms opened! :)

@MikeBorden Indeed.  One new type of "can" is The Filament Bible where the text itself is free from embellishments (other than the usual short pericope headings and a translation footnotes), but you can see LOTS of study notes in an app by simply scanning the page number (after you have set up the app for your Filament Bible edition). It contains all that are usually part of a study bible, including video references to the Bible Project!  Maybe someday there's an "augmented reality" Bible.

@NigelJ Filament Bible has the KJV version too , besides NLT.  They should have the YLT and CSB as well, but then, once you're in the app, it's quite easy to see other translations.  Welcome to the 21st century.

@NigelJ Found a 2018 article about the life of Hermon Hoskier and his contribution to textual criticism: H.C. Hoskier and New Testament Textual Criticism by Prof. Garrick Allen from University of Glasgow.  Also found a 1995 JETS article An Evaluation of John W. Burgon's Use of Patristic Evidence by Mark H. Heuer.  Thought those 2 articles might interest you.

@GratefulDisciple The Critical Text (favoured by the Unitarian Vance Smith and the Unitarian Hort) contains many and various instances of text variations (developed from Sinaiticus and Vaticanus) which erode the relationship of Father and Son and weaken the expression of the Deity of Christ. It is noticeable that both John Burgon and Hermon Hoskier are despised, sidelined and sneered at for their faithful upholding of the Received Text. And some of us choose to stand beside them and share the contempt they endured, in this our own day.

@NigelJ For myself, I don't despise people, I only want each type of scholarship's presuppositions to be spelled out for independent review, i.e. transparency.  I rely more on getting to the author's mindset than a perfect text, and for me Deity of Christ cries out from the text beyond the level of words, guided by the appstolic tradition, and validated by the Holy Spirit testimony on my heart.  I think it's unwise to put your eggs in one basket.  But again, how we love the Lord matters a lot more.  Peace.

A few Bible versions [compare 1 Cor 15:45] use typographical indicators for OT quotations in the NT, like the NET: boldface like the CSB, and the NASB: small caps. This practice appears to have started by the NASB since its first edition in 1971, which also came with some other intricate & fastidious typographical conventions. NASB Preface:

SMALL CAPS in the New Testament are used in the text to indicate Old Testament quotations or obvious references to Old Testament texts. Variations of Old Testament wording are found in New Testament citations depending on whether the New Testament writer translated from a Hebrew text, used existing Greek or Aramaic translations, or paraphrased the material. It should be noted that modern rules for the indication of direct quotation were not used in biblical times; thus, the ancient writer would use exact quotations or references to quotation without specific indication of such. [previous editions read, "...not used in biblical times, thus allowing freedom for omissions or insertions without specific indication of these."]
A STAR (*) is used to mark verbs that are historical presents in the Greek which have been translated with an English past tense in order to conform to modern usage. The translators recognized that in some contexts the present tense seems more unexpected and unjustified to the English reader than a past tense would have been. But Greek authors frequently used the present tense for the sake of heightened vividness, thereby transporting their readers in imagination to the actual scene at the time of occurrence. However, the translators felt that it would be wise to change these historical presents to English past tenses.

The NASB also uses italics for supplied words, which is indeed a fastidious convention in the Bible translations, which seems to have originated with the Geneva Bible. Mark Ward explains how this 'italics convention' is unhelpful, as it maybe rarely be useful only to those beginning to learn the original language, but it hampers the readability for the regular readers.
The boldface or caps emphasis of the OT quotes is also counterproductive for the same reason, as there are instances where the quotation is paraphrased, or an indirect quote is made, and when there is a combination of two different quotes has been made interpretatively. There maybe instances where the translators are not even aware of which source has been alluded to; hence, the practice is inconsistent. With a typographic emphasis, the reader would expect to find exact quotation in the OT, which not the case. Thus, it becomes a definite indicator of a precise quotation such as the modern copy-paste, when no such precision existed in the ancient times.

The new Word on Fire RSV translations italicizes and indents every direct quoted passage.  It doesn't use the normal 2-column format, but has the Bible text filling the entire page (quite luxuriously, it will be a 500 dollar Bible after all - for the complete Leatherbound version)

I didn't notice it that much in the Gospels, but when volume two came out I found that I really liked that format. It makes reading Acts a lot more interesting.

No one can say Catholics don't read Bible anymore :-).  If you could include a screenshot of how WoF RSV quotes OT, that would be great.  Plus the origin of the practice would be good too.  The lavishness makes the Bible a kind of sacramental, true to the Catholic tradition!  It brings back to mind that huge Bible used in the medieval church.

I can't find a single one online, I'll have to take a crummy one with my laptop camera

I'll try to find example too.  I'm sure there's an image out there part of their marketing material, or from Catholic blogs, maybe from here.

@GratefulDisciple thanks for the link, that had one

That's from Acts 8.  A lot of newer Bible translations do indentation without changing the typeface, such as NIV or NLT.  I wonder whether the WoF also do inline quotation in italic as well, like in 1 Cor 15:45?  Another good example is Acts 2:17-21 where not every word was bolded, possibly showing Luke's paraphrase of the OT verses.

1 Cor 15:45 was just quoted, not indented but Acts 2:17-21 was completely indented - even the "God declares" part  - no indication that it is not a quote.  Also, there is no intertext or footnotes in the WoF Bible.  Just a lot of supplemental reading.

Thanks; that's helpful.  So it's rather different than what I'm asking for.

@GratefulDisciple FWIW, I just noticed that the Catholic Book Publishing Company version of the Liturgy of the Hours does this - even with writings of the Church Fathers.  I was reading St. Polycarp's letter to the Phillipians this morning -
new advent has it italicized https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0136.htm  but there's no intertext references in the Liturgy of the Hours, you just have to assume its in the Bible somewhere.
